# Android: How does 500px application load fast

Tags: android, gallery, loading, photo

Hello i am creating a gallery similar to 500px android application. Their app load the HQ image very smooth and quick. I made my own gallery but the speed to load the image is much slower.

How does 500px application work on these function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some libraries which loads images Async and optimizes up to views to load it faster.

Most knowns are; Picasso and Universal Image Library.

Good luck there.